# Xcode SVN can't add JSON directory to repository

Tags: svn, xcode, json-framework

I have added the JSON-framework (Stig B - Google code) to my Classes folder (just the JSON directory as per option 1 instructions).

I had subversion set up which was working fine, until i added this directory. If I modify any existing files that were in the repository, they get marked as M and i can commit those, but i cannot commit the JSON directory or any of the files within it.

I also added a separate JSONController class just in Classes, and cannot commit this either.

Is there something i need to do to get subversion to recursively add directories? I have tried Commit Entire Project, the commit happens, just without the JSON directory or my new controller.

The Add To Repository option is not present for either the directory, or the controller.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove, and re-add the controllers for some reason. Also had to import the JSON directory into the repo directly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you right-click on the folder and choose 'Add to Repository'?  Do you have a .svnignore file in your project directory that may be excluding the JSON folder?

Comment: The Add To Repository option is not present for either the directory, or the controller. I dont have a .svnignore file in the project directory, only the .svn directory.